# Query columns from a table and analyses its’ sources

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to kindly ask you the best approach of analyzing the columns from a materialized table regarding to find their source tables.
As an example: the table to be analyzed CUSTOMERS and the column is customer_name
I would like to have an output like:

| current_name | source_name | source_table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer_name | nombre_cust | nombre_cust |

I would like to create valid_from valid_to columns from the source table like below example.

Desired Output:

Is there any way to analyze the sources of the columns from the final table?
I am using Snowflake and I have checked INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COLUMNS but they did not help me to find the source name of the column or it's source table.

I appreciate with any suggestions.
Thanks,
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

In case you are asking for the source of a particular table: In theory you could have numerous scripts/ways inside or outside of Snowflake to load a target table. Thats why there is no straightforward way with Snowflake capabilities to detect the source of a certain table and it really depends on how you are loading the table.

- Procedure based: You could run `DESC PROCEDURE xyz` to get the procedure code and parse it for source objects.
- INSERT based: If someone is executing a simple `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, you are not getting this dependency unless you are parsing the query history.
- CREATE based: If you are asking for the dependency based on a `CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT` statement, you also need to check the query history.

In case you are asking for views/materialized views: You can checkout OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES in Snowflake: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-dependencies.html. With this you can query, which view depends on which source object. Since materialized views can only be based on one source table, every column is based on this source table or was derived somehow.